# Another rails nested form question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Trying to perform a nested object form. The page loads with no errors, but when I send it, no information gets saved to the organization model.

The SQL call says this ..

```
Parameters: {"commit" => "save", "action"=>"update","_method"=>"put",  "organization"=>{"likes_snacks"=>"0"}, ..
```

Which is right. The 1 and 0 can be changed properly by flipping on and off the checkbox. But that information is just not saved to the database I guess. Any ideas?

HAML:

```
- form_for @user do |f|
  = f.label :username
  = f.text_field :username
.clear
  - fields_for :organization do |org| unless @user.organizations.empty?
    = org.label :likes_snacks, 'Like snacks?'
    = org.check_box :likes_snacks
= f.submit 'save', {class => 'button'}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
  @organization = current_user.organizations.first
end
```

MODELS:

ORGANIZATION.RB:

```
has_many  :users, :through => :organizations_users
```

USER.RB:

```
has_many  :organizations, :through => :organizations_users
```

Comment: Better if you can post the `user` and `organization` model codes too.

Comment: Does the f.text_field :username get saved to the database?

Comment: Are you using `attr_accessible` in your parent model (User) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can save the parent attributes but not the child attributes.

To make child attributes accessible through a nested forms you’ll need to add the “#{child_class_name}_attributes” to the attr_accessible method in your parent class.(Only if use `attr_accessible` in parent model)

So your parent model should look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :organizations_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations
end
```

Also, If you don’t use `attr_accessible` in your parent model this is not necessary.

Comment: I don't use attr_accessible in my User mode. Are you saying that I don't need it then in my model?

Comment: Yah.. also why would :username be connected with :organizations_attributes, or more specifically, why does one attribute of User fall into organizations_attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I think the interesting part here is the linker table :organization_users.

The accepted answer on this so question says you need

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.fields_for :organization_users do |ff|
    ff.fields_for :organization
```

Comment: Ah! Well.. adding that f before fields_for helps. But I got this returned as an error ..
unknown attribute: organization_users
and when I tried it my old way i got this
unknown attribute: organization

Comment: Using "field_for :organizations" (its plural), It returns this  ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in UsersController#update

Organization(#24980000) expected, got Array(#101190)

Comment: Are you doing "ff.fields_for :organization" --- I think the double ff fixes the expectation problems.

Answer (score 0):

Also go through this one of the great article about accepts_nested_attributes_for which is very useful when you want a single form to cater to multiple models.

http://currentricity.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/the-definitive-guide-to-accepts_nested_attributes_for-a-model-in-rails-3/

Hope you will like this.

Thanks

Rameshwar